# I've install the node_modules. Why is there still "no such file or directory"?

Tags: node.js

In my country, I use the mirroring of npm. I have run

```
npm install
```

and get the node_modules directory. But when I try to use

```
npm run serve
```

it causes an error and says

> [10:30:26] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir
>   'C:\Users\acer\personal_profile\wittr\node_modules.3.13.1@node-sass\vendor'
>
> [10:30:26] 'serve' errored after 35 ms
>
> [10:30:26] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(css)'
>
> Message:ENOENT:no such file or directory,scandir'C:\Users\acer\personal_profile\wittr\node_modules.3.13.1@node-sass\vendor'
>
> Details:
>      errno: -4058
>
> code: ENOENT
>
> syscall: scandir
>
> path: C:\Users\acer\personal_profile\wittr\node_modules.3.13.1@node-sass\vendor
>
> Stack:Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir >'C:\Users\acer\personal_profile\wittr\node_modules.3.13.1@node-sass\vendor'

I'm very confused with that, I have installed the node_module, but why causes such an error? Is it something wrong with mirroring? But it says the mirroring is very reliable.

I am not a native speaker. Thank you very much for correcting my expression errors.

Comment: Try `node serve` from your bash.

Comment: delete the folder node_modules\node-sass and then type npm install node-sass

Comment: Did you check your .dockerignore file to make sure node_modules is not added in there. Otherwise docker will not be able to see it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 npm rebuild node-sass
```

would solve your problem

This commonly happens in CI systems because they'll typically run npm install with the default OS Node. Later in their script they'll switch a new version of Node. Native extension are compiled against the version of Node that npm was using during install. This means the new Node cannot see the extension built during install.

In this case, running npm install again doesn't fix the issue because npm thinks it is installed. This is why you must run npm rebuild node-sass.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.